# Windows Rails Server error (mysql, bundler, railties)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, require

I'm just starting a project with ruby (on Windows) and when I run 'rails server' I have this ince ,essage :

> C:\Sites\rails_projects\first_app>rails server
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql-2.9.1-x86-mingw32/lib
>   /mysql.rb:6:in `require': cannot load such file -- mysql/mysql_api
>   (LoadError)
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql-2.9.1-x8
>   6-mingw32/lib/mysql.rb:6:in`rescue in '
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql-2.9.1-x8
>   6-mingw32/lib/mysql.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
>   lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in`require'
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
>   lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
>   lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in`each'
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
>   lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
>   lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in`each'
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
>   lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
>   lib/bundler.rb:132:in`require'
>           from C:/Sites/rails_projects/first_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top
>   (required)>'
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
>   3/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in`require'
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
>   3/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
>   3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in`tap'
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
>   3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
>           from script/rails:6:in`require'
>           from script/rails:6:in `'

Sure I'm mlissing something. Here is my Gemfile : 
source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
gem 'bundler'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'mysql'
gem 'geocode'
gem 'gmaps4rails'
gem 'railties'
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

I have no ruby code files (or I have one, the one generated when you create a new rail projet) as I'm just starting.

Thanks in advance,

---

Thank you for your quick answer, but unfortunately I'm getting same kind of error :

> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/l
>   ib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in `require': 126: Le module spécifié est
>   introuvable.   - 
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/
>   lib/mysql2/1.9/mysql2.so (LoadError)
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-
>   x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in`'
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-
>   x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2.rb:9:in `require'
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-
>   x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2.rb:9:in`'
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
>   lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
>   lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in`block (2 levels) in require'
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
>   lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
>   lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in`block in require'
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
>   lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
>   lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in`require'
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
>   lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
>           from C:/Sites/rails_projects/first_app/config/application.rb:7:in`'
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
>   3/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
>   3/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in`block in '
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
>   3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
>           from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
>   3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in`'
>           from script/rails:6:in `require'
>           from script/rails:6:in`'

```
My files : Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
gem 'bundler'
# gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.11'
gem 'geocode'
gem 'gmaps4rails'
gem 'railties'
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

Database.yml

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'mysql2'
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: db/development.mysql2
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: db/test.mysql2
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: db/production.mysql2
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Thanks again for your help,

Comment: Any ideas would be helpfull guys.

Answer (score 0):

Don't include both `sqlite3` gem and `mysql` gem.

1. Remove existing `Gemfile.lock` file.
2. Remove `gem 'sqlite3'`
3. Replace `gem 'mysql'` with `gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.11'`
4. Run `bundle install` and try again.

Also, make sure you have mysql installed in your system. And configure your `config/database.yml` to use mysql adapter for `development`

**EDIT:**
Copy your `libmysql.dll` from `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL version\bin` (it must be present there, depending upon your version etc of MySQL) to `C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin`.

Comment: thank you for your quick answer, unfortunately still not workig. Please see my comments below

Comment: I have added a step in my answer, try it out and see if it works for you.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have a new error but still have other old ones. Please see below. Thank you again for your patience.

Comment: Hi, my add. posts were deleted by Moderator considering my posts as other questions (which is not case, as its related to my first question which was error on Mysql, railties and bundler). So here is the message I get (in addition to the others on bundler and realties) : C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/l ib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in require': Incorrect MySQL client library version! This gem was compiled for 6.0.0 but the client library is 5.6.11. (RuntimeError)